# How to get certain domain user's access token?

Tags: c++, active-directory, dns, access-token

I'm an Active Directory domain administrator, how to get certain domain user's access token? I wanna use this user's access token to fetch some data from a shared folder that only opens to this him.

Answer (score 1):

**If the user is logged in and you want to Impersonate him using his token then the process is:**

1. Use `WTSEnumerateSessions` to list all the active users of the System in a loop.
2. Compare using `PWTS_SESSION_INFO` info if the user is what you want.
3. IF the user matches then Use `WTSQueryUserToken` to get the token of the user. This Api needs session ID that you will get from `PWTS_SESSION_INFO` struct which you got in step 1 while calling `WTSEnumerateSessions`
4. Duplicate the token using DuplicateTokenEx and then use ImpersonateLoggedOnUser to impersonate that user.
5. Copy the files etc do the work
6. RevertToself.

[Example click here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/11167/)

**IF the user is not logged in and you want to impersonate and do the work using his credentials then:**

1. Use `LogonUser` API to get the token and follow from step 4 from the above option.

Comment: I have some questions.. WTSEnumerateSessions seems to been used for retrieving active user sessions. But how can i been sure that the domain user is accessing this shared folder? Also this method doesn't use my domain administrator permission, is it possible to obtain domain user's access token without it?

Comment: You should be admin on the machine to do admin tasks. The WTS services API gives token of the user logged on into the machine. If the user is not logged then you can get a token of a process which is running as that admin user. And then Duplicate the token and use it. If the user is not logged in and also no process is running as that user then you need to know his credentials. Using Credentials using LogonUser API you get the token. BY this you generate a new token.

Comment: Thx for replying.. I'm not the admin of the remote machine but the admin of the Active Directory domain in which the remote machine is in. the machine my software locates in is somewhere like the Domain Controller. If the WTS APIs is to retrieve the sessions on DC itself, it very likely could not work out i think.. I also thought of LogonUser, but i don't know the domain user's password? is there some logon method without knowing the password?

Comment: WTS API's retrive the token from the current machine i.e the machine on which the software is running and not the DC. If you are domain admin then you should have access to the folder which is accessible to the other domain user because you are domain admin, you can enable the rights if they are denied. As a admin you can get the token of the user if the user is logged in or some process is running on the machine as that user. A token is only created when a user is authenticated on a machine and is logged in or some process is running as that user. Otherwise there is no token.

Comment: i'm domain admin. But if the samba server didn't give me read permission of a folder in the “Share" tab of folder properties, i still can't access it or read its permissions. By logging as a user permitted in the "Share" tab, i can successfully read its permissions.Here's my another thread which explains why i need the access token. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050243/checking-the-permissions-of-a-shared-folder-on-another-windows-failed-with-acces#comment14455376_11050243